# How can I (slice) pattern match on an owned Vec with non-Copy elements?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, slice, ownership

My goal is to move elements out of an owned `Vec`.

```rust
fn f<F>(x: Vec<F>) -> F {
    match x.as_slice() {
        &[a, b] => a,
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

If `F` is copy, that is no problem as one can simply copy out of the slice. When `F` is not, slice patterns seem a no-go, as the slice is read only.

Is there such a thing as an "owned slice", or pattern matching on a `Vec`, to move elements out of `x`?

**Edit:** I now see that this code has the more general problem. The function

```rust
fn f<T>(x: Vec<T>) -> T {
    x[0]
}
```

leaves "a hole in a `Vec`", even though it is dropped right after. This is not allowed. [This post](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-move-out-of-container.html#fn:2) and [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4cbc4u/moving_out_of_a_container_in_rust/d1gx9tb) describe that problem.

That leads to the updated question: How can a `Vec<T>` be properly consumed to do pattern matching?

Comment: Your function returns `F` which means it has to move, copy or clone the item anyway.

Comment: Assuming that you _could_ move an element from the vector, what state would you expect the vector to be in?

Comment: @PeterHall Exactly: I would like to move (question edited).

Comment: @E_net4theRustacean I would like the `Vec` to be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on pattern matching, you could do this:

```
fn f<F>(x: Vec<F>) -> F {
    let mut it = x.into_iter();
    match (it.next(), it.next(), it.next()) {
        (Some(x0), Some(_x1), None) => x0,
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

However, if you just want to retrieve the first element of a 2-element vector (panicking in other cases), I guess I'd rather go with this:

```
fn f<F>(x: Vec<F>) -> F {
    assert_eq!(x.len(), 2);
    x.into_iter().next().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing. It doesn't look good, but I think it's the least worst solution for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a nice pattern in a recent [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/11shqzs/comment/jcebd2c/) that's applicable in case you expect your vector to have exactly the length you are matching against.

The idea to exploit that [`Vec` implements `TryInto<[T; N]>` via `TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-TryFrom%3CVec%3CT%2C%20A%3E%3E-for-%5BT%3B%20N%5D) (since Rust version 1.48). This can be combined with the [`let else` syntax](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html) to pattern match on the try result:

```rust
let Ok([a, b]) = TryInto::<[_; 2]>::try_into(x) else { panic!("Vector has wrong length")};
```

If the vector can have more elements, and you want to discard (drop) them anyway, you could [`truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.truncate) it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use pattern matching with slice patterns in this scenario.

As you have correctly mentioned in your question edits, moving a value out of a `Vec` leaves it with uninitialized memory. This could then cause Undefined Behaviour when the `Vec` is subsequently dropped, because its `Drop` implementation needs to free the heap memory, and possibly drop each element.

There is currently no way to express that your type parameter `F` does not have a `Drop` implementation or that it is safe for it to be coerced from uninitialized memory.

You pretty much have to forget the idea of using a slice pattern and write it more explicitly:

```
fn f<F>(mut x: Vec<F>) -> F {
    x.drain(..).next().unwrap()
}
```

---

If you are dead set on pattern matching, you can use `Itertools::tuples()` to match on tuples instead:

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn f<F>(mut x: Vec<F>) -> F {
    match x.drain(..).tuples().next() {
        Some((a, _)) => a,
        None => panic!()
    }
}
```

Comment: I was starting to realize that same. The simple function that returns a single value can be easily expressed nicely, as you demonstrated. The problem, however, is that my functions look more like [this](https://github.com/vandenheuvel/rust-lp/blob/number_type_system_overhaul/src/io/mps/parsing.rs#L243).

Comment: @vandenheuvel I updated the question to use `drain`, which I think could solve the problem there. It produces an iterator of values that are owned by the iterator.

Comment: I'm now looking into the [`vec_drain_as_slice`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58957) feature, which might just be my saving grace...

Comment: I think you'll run into the same issues with `Drain.as_slice()`. You won't be able to move items out of the slice either.

Comment: If you can match on tuples instead of slice patterns, my edit should help.

Comment: I'm  curious what is the difference. This syntax lets you match on arbitrary* length tuples, so the main difference is syntactic: `&[]` vs `()`.

Comment: All patterns need to be tuples of the same size. In my case, the patterns have different lengths. I suppose I could first differentiate by vector length, and then match on the tuples.

Comment: Another problem is that the tuples can't be of arbitrary length, instead, sizes 0 through 4.

Comment: I was surprised that the limit is 4. I must admit I was expecting it to be more like 15.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve consuming a single element of a vector is to swap the last element with the element you want to consume, and then pop the last element

```
fn f<F>(mut x: Vec<F>) -> F {
    match x.as_slice() {
        [_a, _b] => {
            x.swap(0, 1);
            x.pop().unwrap() // returns a
        },
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

The code uses an `unwrap` which isn't elegant.

Comment: +1 for the creativity of the contribution, but it doesn't address the bigger problem of doing pattern matching...

Comment: This is in the standard library: `x.swap_remove(0)`